# How do I find the profileID when creating new users with the SalesForce data loader

Tags: apex

I have a CSV created that has all of the required column headers included. My import is failing of course because profileID is required and I do not have this.

How can I get the profileID of a user, if the user does not exist?

I am completely at a loss here.

I have searched for an answer to this but nothing I have read has told me how to get around this. I have all of the other required fields included in my CSV. The only field that the data loader is failing on is of course; profileID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Profiles live in a separate table and are assigned to a user. Every salesforce.com user is required to have a profile. You can find the profile Ids in one of a few ways.

1. You can export them using the DataLoader or some similar tool. They live in the table called Profile. At a minimum, you will need the Id and the Name fields.
2. Alternatively, you can just navigate to the profile via setup (Setup > Manage Users > Profiles) and click on the profile that you want. The Profile Id is the 15 digit alphanumeric id that appears in the URL when you click to view the profile. Copy that Id and use it in your import spreadsheet.

Comment: Ahhh ok  I get what they're asking for now.